# How to define the custom parameter of a record in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

There is a custom parameter for the StodolaTurbine component in the ThermoSysPro library, in the diagram view of the turbine component, I could see that the custom parameter belongs to a record. But there is no parameter for this record, how could I add one more custom parameter in this case?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every modifier you set shows up in the parameter window . You can not only set modifiers for parameters, but for more or less everything that is not final: so also for all variables and component instances, regardless if they are visible in the parameter window or not. Dymola will display such modifiers in the section 'Custom parameters'.

There are several ways to set such modifiers:

1. Typing the modifier equation directly in the text layer
2. Using the tab 'Add modifiers' in the parameter window of a component
3. Using show component to open instances and setting a parameter in a sub-component

In older Dymola versions these modifiers were simply shown in the general parameter group, which lead to confusion. So they moved it to the 'Custom parameter' section.

#### Example

Lets use the simple code below to demonstrate the three different methods.

```
package Demo
  model StepSine
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Step step annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,20},{20,60}})));
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput y annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{100,-10},{120,10}})));
    Modelica.Blocks.Math.Add add annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{60,-10},{80,10}})));
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine sine annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,-60},{20,-20}})));
  equation 
    connect(add.y, y) annotation (Line(points={{81,0},{110,0}}, color={0,0,127}));
    connect(step.y, add.u1) annotation (Line(points={{22,40},{40,40},{40,6},{58,6}}, color={0,0,127}));
    connect(sine.y, add.u2) annotation (Line(points={{22,-40},{40,-40},{40,-6},{58,-6}}, color={0,0,127}));
  end StepSine;

  model Example
    StepSine stepSine annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-8,-10},{12,10}})));
  end Example;
end Demo;
```

Here we created the class `StepSine`, which simply adds a step to a sine signal. None of the parameters of the components are propagated, but with the methods described above we can still set them in `Example`.

1. Using the text layer

   1. Go to the text layer and type `StepSine stepSine(add.k1=-1)`
   2. Check the parameter window of `stepSine`. You got your first custom parameter.
2. Using 'Add modifiers'

   1. Open the parameter window of `stepSine` in `Example`
   2. Switch to the tab 'Add Modifiers'
   3. Type `step.height=1` and click OK
   4. Check the parameter window again. You got your second custom parameter.
3. Using 'Show component'

   1. Open `stepSine` using right-click -> show component
   2. Then open the parameter window of `sine` and enter e.g. 3 for the amplitude
   3. Check the parameter window of `stepSine` again. You got the third custom parameter.